# Trigger causes system null pointer exception

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm having problem with my trigger.Please help me to resolve  this system null pointer exception

```
trigger theatreupdate on Transaction__c (before insert) 
{

    for(Transaction__c t:Trigger.new)
    {

        t.TheaterT__r.Number_Of_Seats_Sold__c=0;
    }
//TheaterT__r-parent of Transaction__c


}
```

Comment: Trigger.new variable does not hold references to related objects. Check this link : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/97272/16304

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update parent fields directly. Here is how to do it

```
trigger theatreupdate on Transaction__c (before insert) 
{
    Set<String> parentIds = new Set<String>();
    for(Transaction__c t:Trigger.new)
    {
       parentIDs.add(t.TheaterT__c);
    }

    List<Theater__c> theatres = [select Number_Of_Seats_Sold__c from Theater__c where id = :parentIds];

    for (TheaterT__c th : theatres_ }
       th.Number_Of_Seats_Sold__c=0;
    }

    update theatres;

}
```

Comment: Note to @Remya that in general, these kinds of things work better in after triggers as often, the object you want to insert or update may need the id of the triggered object - and the ID is not available until the 'after insert trigger. Not true in your specific use case but good to remember.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update parent fields directly in trigger. You have to create new instance and then do update. Only current object level fields can be updated.